# Henselian field which is not local field

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm looking for a henselian field which is not local field.

Henselian field is defined as a filed which has non-archimedian value, and in whose valuation field, hensel lemma holds.

Ofcourse local fields are henselian field, but I couldn't find any other example.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take any valued field that has nothing to do with number theory, and take its henselianization. That will give you a henselian field which is not a local field.

Maybe an exemple that you might be more familiar with is $\mathbb{C}_p$, the complex p-adic field. It's complete thus henselian, but is of course not a local field.